# How to get Class object without instance?

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, nsobject, foundation

Is there any way to get the result of:

```
    NSObject *a = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    [a class];
```

Without instantiating?
I wish to pass **Class** object to function as argument, and check it then. Like this:

```
    - (void) pushControllerOfClass: (Class) aClass
    {
        if([aClass isSubclassOfClass: *what should I write here?*]) {
        ...
        }
    }
```

Intuitively, I've tried to write

```
        if([aClass isSubclassOfClass: UIViewController]) {
```

But it doesn't work.
Thx for future response.

**Update:**
Is such a function considered bad in ObjectiveC?
I've refactored code from Nahavandipoor's book *iOS 5 Programming Cookbook*. 
It was like that:

```
- (void) pushSecondController{
    SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc]
                                             initWithNibName:nil 
                                             bundle:NULL];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];
}
```

As for me, this is kind of bad function:
It doesn't parametrized when it should be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with:

```
 if([aClass isSubclassOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
```

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your question, you don't need an instance of an object to get its class. You can get it directly from the class like:

```
[NSString class];
[YourClass class];
```

However, if all you are wanting is a method that can push any view controller you give it, then you can just use UIViewController as the parameter type:

```
- (void)pushAnyViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

This will take any view controller that is a subclass of UIViewController and push it onto the navigation stack.

If you really want the method to handle the allocations as well you can do:

```
- (void)pushViewControllerClass:(Class)viewControllerClass
{
    if ([viewControllerClass isSubclassOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
    {
        id viewController = [[viewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Class viewControllerClass = [MyViewController class];
[self pushViewControllerClass:viewControllerClass];
```

Just make sure that the nib is named the same as the class if you are using one.

Comment: You can also write `NSString.class` and `YourClass.class`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `[UIViewController class]` to get the class object.

Comment: You can also write `UIViewController.class`.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a class method on most classes to get the class.

If you find yourself doing this often, perhaps revisit your design?

Comment: Answered in OP update, because there is no code formatting in comments.